# Elixir: Method arguments being treated as function

Tags: elixir

I am trying to print nodes at a give level in a Binary Tree. I have written a method to do this and a guard clause to handle the base condition (which I have not included in the question)

```
def get_node_at_level(root, height) do
   get_node_at_level(root.left, height -1)
   get_node_at_level(root.right, height -1)
end
```

this method is giving me error saying that

> height -1" looks like a function call but there is a variable named "height", please use explicit parentheses or even spaces
>       (stdlib) lists.erl:1353: :lists.mapfoldl/3
>       (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Replace `height -1` with `height - 1`.

Since functions can be called without parenthesis in Elixir, `height` followed by `-` followed by `1` could either mean `height` minus `1` or calling the function `height` with argument `-1`. Elixir decided that `x-1` and `x - 1` should mean `x` minus `1` while `x -1` should issue an error (probably) because it might look like you're calling a function, and asks the user to either use `x-1` or `x - 1` or `x(-1)` instead.